# Symfony 6.3 / Post Request with MapRequestPayload

Tags: php, symfony, attributes, doctrine

I would like to use the `MapRequestPayload` attribute to create an entity from the POST request data.

I then validate this and then save it.

This works very well so far, but how do you deal with data from a select?

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "firstname": "test",
    "company_id": 486
}
```

compay_id is a select in a frontend.

This is of course ignored when assigning, which is ok because it shouldn't be created, but the relationship should be saved.

My approach would now be the following, but it doesn't work because the MapEntity attribute refers to the Request Query.

```
    public function add(
        #[MapRequestPayload] Person $person,
        #[MapEntity(id: 'company_id')] Company $company
    ): JsonResponse
    {
        $person->setCompany($company);
    }
```

Do you know a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and the solution can change accordingly with your needs

Remember that your payload does not represent an actual entity of your application, it represent a DTO

So one solution is to have a separete DTO:

```
<?php
    
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Dto;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[Assert\Cascade]
class MyDTO {
    #[Assert\NotNull]
    public string $name;
    #[Assert\NotNull]
    public string $surname;
    #[Assert\NotNull]
    public int $company_id;         
}
```

and map the DTO into your entities in the controller.

The other solution is to change some logic:
why are you adding a company id in the user and you require to specify the user data in the payload?

I guess:
I have a user and I need to add a company -> I have to implement a post request with /user/{id}/addCompany and I can select the user (with a repo) and then adding the company like this:

```
#[Route('user/{id}/add-company', name: 'user-add-company', methods: ['POST'])]
public function update(
    int $id,
    #[MapRequestPayload]
    Company $company,
): Response {
    $user = $userRepo->getById($id);
    
    $user->setCompany($company);


    return $this->json('OK');
}
```

Or I need to create a user AND the company together:

```
#[Route('/user-with-company', name: 'user-with-company', methods: ['POST'])]
public function createUserWithCompany(
    #[MapRequestPayload]
    User $user;
): Response {
    $user = $userRepo->create($user);

    return $this->json('OK');
}
```

And your User object should contain a property company. In this case you should modify your incoming payload:

```
{
    name:"John",
    surname:"Doe",
    company: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Acme"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be two solution first via JavaScript.

```js
fetch('api/users?company_id='.$companyId, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: "test",
    firstName: "test"
  })


})
```

Second via Symfony's ValueResolverInterface

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/value_resolver.html#adding-a-custom-value-resolver

Comment: Thanks for the reply

The JS solution doesn't seem to be a good one to me, as GET values should be used for storage. It seems more like a hack to me.
I thought about building my own value resolver, but it would have to be very clever or there would be a lot of them.

I also have the same or similar topic with "update", where the complexity would be even greater, as you would have two entities, one from the data set that you want to change and one that is created via "MapRequestPayload". Bringing this together is also another issue.

My goal was to replace Symfony Forms with it.